# SQL query to return all rows that contain duplicate data from one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with card numbers and names. Some of those names are the same, meaning they have multiple cards. How can I select all the rows where the name occurs more than once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following may be the solution you are looking for

```
Select * from CardTable where cardid in ( select cardid from CardTable group by cardid having count(cardid) > 1)
```

Comment: The subquery is only necessary if you want to return columns other than the name.

Comment: -1: Your query does not work and will return no rows. count(cardid) = 1 if group by cardid, for all rows.

Comment: if you could explain why you think you query would return any rows (or where I am wrong) I'll be more than happy to correct my score. Do you consider cardid to be a name or id? Question states that there are card numbers and names.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.name
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
SELECT        * 
FROM cards    c1 
INNER JOIN    cards c2 on c1.name = c2.name 
WHERE         c2.id <> c1.id
```

Comment: you'll get the results many times if ANY(select count(*) from cards group by name) > 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as n, [name]
from table1
group by [name]
having n > 1
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow you to reference column aliases in the GROUP BY or HAVING clause - you'll get "Invalid column name 'n'", at least on SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the whole rows, here is a solution that will work on sql 7 and up

```
SELECT t1.* FROM(
 SELECT t.name
    FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.name
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
  JOIN YourTable t1 on t2.name = t1.name
```

Comment: Is the performance of this query as good as SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE t.name IN (subquery) on MS SQL?